# GCJ - Hamiltonian Cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

[Code jam problem](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32004#s=p2) is the following:

You are given a complete undirected graph with N nodes and K "forbidden" edges. N <= 300, K <= 15. Find the number of Hamiltonian cycles in the graph that do not use any of the K "forbidden" edges.

Unfortunately the explanations of this here on stack and throughout the web are very insufficient. I can figure out HamCycles for a certain 'n' : (n-1)! / 2 .

And I can do the short set with dynamic programming.

But I don't get all the subset bologna, how to make it O^K? I'm in Python and have yet to decipher the C++ available. Eventually I'm sure I will take the time to learn C++ and then I will decipher it. But in the meantime, why can't someone explain this better somewhere on the web? They are always half explanations.

Answer (score 8):

It might help if you point to the explanations that are lacking, but I'll try anyway...

The O(2<sup>k</sup>)-based solution uses the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). Given that there are ***k*** forbidden edges, there are ***2<sup>k</sup>*** subsets of those edges, including the set itself and the empty set. For instance, if there were 3 forbidden edges: {A, B, C}, there would be 2<sup>3</sup>=8 subsets: {}, {A}, {B}, {C}, {A,B}, {A,C}, {B,C}, {A,B,C}.

For each subset, you calculate the number of cycles that include at least all the edges in that subset . If the number of cycles containing edges ***s*** is ***f(s)*** and ***S*** is the set of all forbidden edges, then by the inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of cycles without any forbidden edges is:

```
 sum, for each subset s of S: f(s) * (-1)^|s|
```

where |***s***| is the number of elements in ***s***. Put another way, the sum of the number of cycles with any edges *minus* the number of cycles with at least 1 forbidden edge *plus* the number with at least 2 forbidden edges, ...

Calculating ***f(s)*** is not trivial -- at least I didn't find an easy way to do it. You might stop and ponder it before reading on.

To calculate ***f(s)***, start with the number of permutations of the nodes not involved with any ***s*** nodes. If there are ***m*** such nodes, there are ***m***! permutations, as you know. Call the number of permutations ***c***.

Now examine the edges in ***s*** for chains. If there are any impossible combinations, such as a node involved with 3 edges or a subcycle within ***s***, then ***f(s)*** is 0.

Otherwise, for each chain increment ***m*** by 1 and multiply ***c*** by ***2m***. (There are ***m*** places to put the chain in the existing permutations and the factor of 2 is because the chain can be forwards or backwards.) Finally, ***f(s)*** is ***c***/(***2m***). The last division converts permutations to cycles.

Comment: Wow, excellent! That's was a MUCH better explanation than I have seen before. And actually made it through my thick skull. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, finally got the large data set solved :). The part I'm trying to understand is the reasoning for the (-1)^|s|, why would every all the odd # elements be subtracted and the even added? I'll have to read more about the inclusion-exclusion principle - obviously I don't have the background in math, I'm a neurobiology/biochemist.

Comment: @xan I know this comment comes out of nowhere, but it think the answer should be `f(s) * (-1)^(|s|+1)` (according to wikipedia)...

Comment: @RontogiannisAristofanis You may have to expand on that. I think this sum is different from the generic inclusion/exclusion, if that's what you're referring to, because this is subtractive rather than additive.

Comment: @xan you are right, I double checked the inclusion-exclusion principle  article. What I proposed was correct, but not applicable in the current problem :)

Comment: can you define chain? so lets say my set under consideration is {A, B};
A => 1<-> 2
B => 2<->3.
Is that one chain (1-2-3)?

Comment: @patmyback yes, a chain is a sequence of connected edges