# How to find Hamiltonian Cycle in a Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve the Hamiltonian Cycle problem. I am able to find a path with all the vertices, but unable to complete the cycle.

Can someone provide me with an algorithm to find the cycle?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Determining if a graph has a [Hamiltonian Cycle is a NP-complete problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). This means that we can **check** if a given path is a Hamiltonian cycle in polynomial time, but we don't know any polynomial time algorithms capable of **finding** it.

The only algorithms that can be used to find a Hamiltonian cycle are **exponential time algorithms**. Some of them are

- Brute force search
- Dynamic programming
- Other exponential but nevertheless faster algorithms that you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the most basic problems in computer science, there are plenty solutions depending on what you want: start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem#Algorithms

There are also SO answers related: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038367/gcj-hamiltonian-cycles)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387523/how-can-i-find-the-number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-a-complete-undirected-graph)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this below link which i found will help you lot with clear explanation...... http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/19092

Answer (score 0):

Use a SAT solver if possible. They don't have the good theoretical time limits of the algorithms in the Wikipedia article, but in practice they can often solve them surprisingly quickly.