# Algorithm to find a path to all cities

Tags: path-finding, traveling-salesman

I am hoping there is already a straight forward algorithm as a solution to this but not sure what this type of problem is called and therefore where to look for a solution. 
It is in some ways similar to the traveling salesman problem but I think it should be much simpler.
The main difference to the problem is there are **limited connections (3 to 6 per city) between cities**.
The path **does not need to return to starting**, only that it **visits each city just once**. Also the **connections are all the same length so the full path length will always be the same (NOT A SHORTEST DISTANCE PROBLEM)**. There are 84 cites and therefore the final path will always be 87 units long.
Basically I am looking for any solution that can from a random start, get to all cities just once. I am hoping for a "random" solution that won't look orderly. 
Any suggestions on what this type of problem is called and where I might find an algorithm.
Thanks.

Comment: This question may be better placed in the Computer Science Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Hamiltonian Path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem). Unfortunately, this problem is NP-Complete, although the fact that the vertices in your graph have a limited degree with help its tractability. You can find more information about solving this problem on the linked Wikipedia page or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107545/how-to-find-hamiltonian-cycle-in-a-graph).