# Is it guarantee for greedy algorithm to find a solution?

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I want to find a Hamiltonian circuit. If my algorithm has no edges to visit, should it return false or go back to the place where it can do something?

Answer (score 2):

Hamilton circuit finding is an [NP-hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), so by consequence there is no greedy algorithm to always successfully find one when it is possible. This means indeed that an algorithm that initially takes a greedy approach, and is unsuccessful, will need to backtrack and choose another route to try again.

See also [How to find Hamiltonian Cycle in a Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107545/how-to-find-hamiltonian-cycle-in-a-graph)

Comment: There is something about the way this answer was formulated which is very appealing.